# how to set alarm that will call on exact date and time of recycler view items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, alarmmanager

I have recycler item in fragment. And for each time I to  have call a reminder(alarm) of its selected date and time.I am adding items from addUpdateActivity to TodoFragment.

And i am totally confused what is a correct way to call method to achieve alarm for each recyclerview item

**Receiver Class**

```
class TodoReceiverClass : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private lateinit var notification: Notification
    private lateinit var nmc: NotificationManagerCompat
    val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
    val REQUEST_CODE = 1
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "notification"
    val title = "Alarm Received"
    val message = "Wake up your alarm is running..."

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        vibrationAndRingtone(context)
        showNotification(context)
    }

    private fun vibrationAndRingtone(context: Context) {
//        val vibrator = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
//        vibrator.vibrate(1000)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Received! Wake up! Wake up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        var alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM)
        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        }
        val ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri)
        ringtone.play()
    }
```

**Adapter Class**

```
class ToDoAdapter(
    val context: Context, var todoInterface: TodoInterface?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var todoList = arrayListOf<ToDoPojo>()

    var dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.US)
    var inputDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy", Locale.US)
    var date: Date? = null
    private lateinit var outputDateString: String

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_todo_row_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val todoListPos = todoList[position]

        date = inputDateFormat.parse(todoListPos.date)
        outputDateString = date?.let { dateFormat.format(it) }.toString()

        val items1: Array<String> = outputDateString.split(" ").toTypedArray()
        val day = items1[0]
        val dd = items1[1]
        val month = items1[2]

        holder.tvDate.text = day + "\n" + dd + "\n" + month
        holder.tvTitle.text = todoListPos.title
        holder.tvDescription.text = todoListPos.description
        holder.tvTime.text = "Time : " + todoListPos.time
        holder.tvNotifyBefore.text = "Notify : "+ todoListPos.notifyBefore

        holder.ivMore.setOnClickListener {
            showPopUpMenu(holder.ivMore, position)
        }
        todoInterface?.onAlarmAlert(todoListPos)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todoList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val tvDate: AppCompatTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date)
        val tvTitle: AppCompatTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title)
        val tvDescription: AppCompatTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description)
        val tvTime: AppCompatTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time)
        val tvNotifyBefore: AppCompatTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notify_before)
        val ivMore: AppCompatImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_more)
    }

    private fun showPopUpMenu(view: View?, position: Int) {
        val todoListPos: ToDoPojo = todoList[position]
        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(context, view)
        popupMenu.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.todo_item_menu, popupMenu.menu)
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item: MenuItem ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.delete -> {
                    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog)
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.delete_confirmation)
                        .setMessage(R.string.sureToDelete)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes) { _, _ ->
                            todoInterface?.onDeleteClick(todoListPos)
                            notifyItemRemoved(position)
                            Toast.makeText(context,todoListPos.title +" deleted!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no) { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }.show()
                }
                R.id.update -> {
                    todoInterface?.onUpdateClick(todoListPos)
                }
                R.id.complete -> {
                    val dialog = Dialog(context, R.style.Theme_MyDailyLife)
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_completed_layout)
                    val btnOk = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnOk)
                    btnOk.setOnClickListener {
                        todoInterface?.onDeleteClick(todoListPos)
                        dialog.dismiss()
                        Toast.makeText(context,todoListPos.title +" completed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
                    dialog.show()
                }
                R.id.share_task -> {
                    todoInterface?.onAlarmAlert(todoListPos)
                }

            }
            false
        }
        popupMenu.show()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun updateList(newList: List<ToDoPojo>) {
        todoList.clear()
        todoList.addAll(newList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    interface TodoInterface {
        fun onDeleteClick(todoItem: ToDoPojo)

        fun onUpdateClick(todoItem: ToDoPojo)

        fun onAlarmAlert(todoItem: ToDoPojo)
    }

}
```

**Todo Fragment**

```
 override fun onAlarmAlert(todoItem: ToDoPojo) {
        val itemDate: Array<String> = todoItem.date.split("-").toTypedArray()
        val day = itemDate[0].toInt()
        val month = itemDate[1] .toInt()
        val year = itemDate[2] .toInt()

        val itemsTime: Array<String> = todoItem.time.split(":"," ").toTypedArray()
        val hour = itemsTime[0].toInt()
        val min = itemsTime[1].toInt()
        val am_pm = itemsTime[2]

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
//        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, am_pm);

        calendar.set(year,month,day)
        val timeInMillis = calendar.timeInMillis

        val alarmManager : AlarmManager = activity?.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(activity, TodoReceiverClass::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC,   timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
        Toast.makeText(activity, "$year $month $day  ringing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

**AddUpdateActivity**

```
 private fun onClick() {
        val type = intent.getStringExtra("type")
        if (type.equals("update")) {
            val title = intent.getStringExtra("title")
            val description = intent.getStringExtra("description")
            val time = intent.getStringExtra("time")
            val date = intent.getStringExtra("date")
            val notifyBefore = intent.getStringExtra("notifyBefore")
            noteID = intent.getIntExtra("todoId", -1)
            btnDone.text = "Update Todo"
            tvPreview.text= "Change the details what you want to update"
            etTitle.setText(title)
            etDescription.setText(description)
            etTime.setText(time)
            etDate.setText(date)
//            spnNotifyTodo.prompt= notifyBefore
        } else {
            btnDone.text = "Add New"
        }

        btnDone.setOnClickListener {
            val title = etTitle.text.toString()
            val description = etDescription.text.toString()
            val time = etTime.text.toString()
            val date = etDate.text.toString()
            val selectedTodoNotify = spnNotifyTodo.selectedItem.toString()

            if (type.equals("update")) {
                if (title.isNotEmpty() && description.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val updatedTodo = ToDoPojo(title, description, time,date, selectedTodoNotify)
                    updatedTodo.id = noteID
                    todoViewModel.updateToDoExistingItem(updatedTodo)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "$title updated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            } else {
                if (title.isNotEmpty() && description.isNotEmpty()) {
                    todoViewModel.insertToDoItem(ToDoPojo(title, description, time,date, selectedTodoNotify))
                    Toast.makeText(this, "$title added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
            this.finish()
        }
    }
```

** Manifest **

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />


  `  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyDailyLife"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ChatActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.AddUpdateActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".LogicClass.TodoReceiverClass"/>
    </application>
```

Comment: Are you storing alarm's date and time somewhere?Do You want to start alarm when app is closed?

Comment: Yes I am storing date and time in pojo class and getting exact date and time of particular item and want to set alarm as reminder on selected date and time of each items even when phone locked or not